# Clang(LLVM) compile with frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, llvm, llvm-clang

I am using:

> clang -ObjC -framework UIKit -o /var/compiled/c /Documents/Source/main.m

In OS X terminal. I also tried UIKit.framework, but I am getting

> Fatal Error: 'UIKit/UIKit.h' not found

with both.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific.

Comment: How did you get this error.

Comment: When using 'clang -ObjC -framework UIKit -o /var/compiled/c /Documents/Source/main.m' in OS X terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiling for iOS without using Xcode is not easy. In your case, you're trying to use an iOS framework but you're using neither the iOS toolchain's compiler nor the iOS SDK.

If you look at the compile transcript for an Xcode project you'll see some of the flags that are necessary. Things you'll need include:

- `xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang` to choose the correct compiler and SDK
- `-arch armv7s` to choose the correct CPU architecture
- `-mios-version-min=6.1` to set a minimum deployment target

Some older versions of Xcode also require `-isysroot=/path/to/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk` to choose the correct SDK because `xcrun` did not do it automatically.

Answer (score 5):

This has been already answered in the Apple developer forum, you can find the whole discussion in [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3754858?start=0&tstart=0). In the answer marked as the solution to the question they say:

1 - check your PATH variable first:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

2 - assuming /System/Library/Frameworks is not included in PATH, add it:

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/System/Library/Frameworks
```

3 -now we're ready for Mr. Kochun's incantation:

```
$ clang -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation main.m prog1
```

Comment: I did find that too, but it didn't help me. What shall I do after specifying the 'PATH'? 'clang -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation -framework UIKit ...' Does give me the same error.

Comment: have you tried making `export $PATH` after set the new value?

Comment: moreover, in the new version of the Mac OS the right path is `/Library/Frameworks`

Comment: I have it installed on /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/

Comment: For me it's /System/Library/Frameworks also tried 'export $PATH'. Didn't work for me.

Comment: So I'm now trying 'clang -fobjc-arc -framework UIKit -o o main.m' still getting the same error. Also tried with Foundation and UIKit.

Comment: -iframework<arg> - Add directory to SYSTEM framework search path