# When cross compiling static libaries, how do I validate the host, target, etc?

Tags: ios, clang, static-libraries, cross-compiling, configure

When cross compiling, I need to set the host, build, and target flags.
What is the format, and how do I acquire and validate, the host, build, and target flags?  What's the format?

For my computer, do I compile static libraries using x86_64-apple-darwin, i386-apple-darwin, i686-apple-darwin, x86_64-apple-darwin13, i386-apple-darwin13, i686-apple-darwin13, or something else?  Is there an easy way to get or validate these?

What about iOS devices?  What to use for arm64?

Comment: You should be OK with just `-arch` and `-mios-version-min`/`-mmacosx-version-min`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387484/clangllvm-compile-with-frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the compiler `-arch` and flags (`CC`, `CFLAGS`) for, say, the iOS device, then it should be sufficient to use `--host=arm-apple-darwin`. Provided the autotools that were used to generate all the auxiliary files (`config.guess`, etc) are recent enough.

I don't really know what 'rocket' is about, but the site has some [examples](http://librocket.com/wiki/documentation/BuildingFreeTypeForiOS) of cross-compilation for iOS. Unless you're building a [compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Configure-Terms.html)or a toolchain, you're unlikely to need the `--target` triple.

Comment: Unfortunately, after using your suggestion, the `lipo -info libmylib.a` always shows the arch as `x86_64`, not `arm64` that I feed to the `-arch` option.