# Include search path on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, osx-yosemite, clang++

**I just to change the include search path order (I believe).**

---

I'd like to change the include search path. Especially, I need `/usr/local/include` first.

But it doesn't change because of duplicate. How can I change it?

I suppose there's default setting, because paths I don't specify appears. Like `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`, `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/include`

```
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.10.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name test_common.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 241.9 -v -gdwarf-2 -coverage-file /Users/machidahiroaki/RubymineProjects/caffe/.build_debug/src/caffe/test/test_common.o -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0 -D DEBUG -D CPU_ONLY -I /usr/local/include -I /usr/local/include -I /Users/machidahiroaki/anaconda/include -I /Users/machidahiroaki/anaconda/include/python2.7 -I /Users/machidahiroaki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I .build_debug/src -I ./src -I ./include -I /usr/local/atlas/include -stdlib=libstdc++ -O0 -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/machidahiroaki/RubymineProjects/caffe -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -pthread -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.10.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -vectorize-slp -o .build_debug/src/caffe/test/test_common.o -x c++ src/caffe/test/test_common.cpp
clang -cc1 version 6.0 based upon LLVM 3.5svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10/x86_64"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.0.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/i686-apple-darwin8/"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/local/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/machidahiroaki/anaconda/include
 /Users/machidahiroaki/anaconda/include/python2.7
 /Users/machidahiroaki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
 .build_debug/src
 ./src
 ./include
 /usr/local/atlas/include
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

---

### Library search paths

```
Machida-no-MacBook-Air:caffe machidahiroaki$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld -v ...
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-241.9
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Library/Frameworks/
    /System/Library/Frameworks/
```

For sure this is the `ld` done in `make`.

```
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -dylib -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -t -o .build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/atlas/lib .build_debug/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o .build_debug/src/caffe/proto/caffe_pretty_print.pb.o .build_debug/src/caffe/blob.o .build_debug/src/caffe/common.o .build_debug/src/caffe/data_transformer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/internal_thread.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layer_factory.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/accuracy_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/argmax_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/base_data_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/bnll_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/concat_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_pooling_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_relu_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_softmax_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_tanh_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/data_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/dummy_data_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/eltwise_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/flatten_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/hinge_loss_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/infogain_loss_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/loss_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/lrn_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/memory_data_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/multinomial_logistic_loss_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/mvn_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/neuron_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/power_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/silence_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/slice_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/split_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/tanh_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/threshold_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/layers/window_data_layer.o .build_debug/src/caffe/net.o .build_debug/src/caffe/solver.o .build_debug/src/caffe/syncedmem.o .build_debug/src/caffe/util/benchmark.o .build_debug/src/caffe/util/im2col.o .build_debug/src/caffe/util/insert_splits.o .build_debug/src/caffe/util/io.o .build_debug/src/caffe/util/math_functions.o .build_debug/src/caffe/util/upgrade_proto.o -framework Accelerate -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lboost_system -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lpthread -lboost_thread-mt -lcblas -lstdc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

**So... where does this path `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1` come from?**

---

Did I get some hints?

```
Machida-no-MacBook-Air:caffe machidahiroaki$ g++ -print-search-dirs
install: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/
programs: =/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/bin/
libraries: =/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/lib/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/../../../:/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/lib/
Machida-no-MacBook-Air:caffe machidahiroaki$ clang++ -print-search-dirs
programs: =/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
libraries: =/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0
M
```

I don't know if it has to do with the problem...

```
Machida-no-MacBook-Air:caffe machidahiroaki$ gcc -print-search-dirs
install: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/
programs: =/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/bin/
libraries: =/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/lib/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/../../../:/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/:/usr/lib/
Machida-no-MacBook-Air:caffe machidahiroaki$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 5.0.0 20141005 (experimental)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

**Wait, `export CFLAGS="-I/path/to/preferred/HDF5/hdf5.h"` would not work...**

Specify nothing

```
Machida-no-MacBook-Air:caffe machidahiroaki$ echo | "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -Wp,-v -stdlib=libstdc++ -x c++ - -fsyntax-only
clang -cc1 version 6.0 based upon LLVM 3.5svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

**Can't specify a header file!!**

```
Machida-no-MacBook-Air:caffe machidahiroaki$ echo | "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -Wp,-v -stdlib=libstdc++ -x c++ - -fsyntax-only -I/usr/local/include/hdf5.h
clang -cc1 version 6.0 based upon LLVM 3.5svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/hdf5.h"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

As expected, the duplicate directory is ignored and **the order does not change.**

```
Machida-no-MacBook-Air:caffe machidahiroaki$ echo | "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -Wp,-v -stdlib=libstdc++ -x c++ - -fsyntax-only -I/usr/local/include/
clang -cc1 version 6.0 based upon LLVM 3.5svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/local/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

---

**But, I found `clang`'s `-include` option, which is able to specify a file!**

Comment: ok, thank for your advise. I'm trying to get lib search paths now.

Comment: I added some more information. Are you *certain* you want a *Library Search Path*. You keep naming it specifically, but you also keep looping back to header include paths.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it. Yes, you are right. I'm confused about the difference between a Library Search Path and Header Include Paths. Header Include Paths is what I mean.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the Include Path of Compilers like gcc is configured when <code>./configure</code> and hardcoded... So maybe I need to reinstall it...

Comment: `... include path of compilers like gcc is configured...` - ***if*** `configure` is written properly, it will uptake anything you supply through `CPP`, `CC`, `CXX`, `CPPFLAGS`, `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`. But there are lots of projects that you have to manually open the Makefile after `configure` and fix it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I'd like to change library search path...

At compile time, you augment the library search path with `-L`. You cannot delete paths; you can only add paths that have a "higher" preference than existing paths.

At runtime, you use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` and friends to change the library search path. See [`dyld(1)` OS X Man Pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html).

Usually you use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to ensure a particular library is loaded rather than the system one. Its a way to override default behavior. `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` is used to provide a library that's not a system one. Its less intrusive because you don't displace system paths.

### ----------

> I need /usr/local/include first...

Sounds a bit odd to me, but...

```
$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/include
$ clang ...
```

### ----------

***IF*** you are cross-compiling from the command line, you should do something like this. The trick is to use `--sysroot` to automatically bring in the headers and libraries for the platform, rather than hacking them with `-I`, `-L` and `-l`.

```
# Put cross compile tools on the PATH first
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/:$PATH"

# C compiler
export CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang

# C++ compiler
export CXX=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++

# SYSROOT brings in platform headers and libraries, No need for -I, -L and -l.
SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk

# Compiler flags
export CFLAGS="-march armv7 -march armv7s --sysroot=$SYSROOT"

# Compiler flags
export CXXFLAGS="-march armv7 -march armv7s --sysroot=$SYSROOT"

# Using defualt C++ runtime
$CXX $CXXFLAGS foo.c -o foo.exe
```

You can also specify GNU's runtime with `-stdlib=libstdc++`, and LLVM's runtime with `-stdlib=libc++`.

### ----------

Based on your updates:

> `<ld command and output omitted>` 
>   where does this path /usr/include/c++/4.2.1 come from??

`/usr/include/c++/4.2.1` is *not* in your ***Library Search Path***. Its just not there.

That's a header include path, and you specify it with `-I`.

If you want to see your header include paths for `libstdc++` and `libc++`, do this:

```
# GNU C++ runtime
$ echo | /usr/local/bin/clang++ -Wp,-v -stdlib=ibstdc++ -x c++ - -fsyntax-only
```

And:

```
# LLVM C++ runtime
$ echo | /usr/local/bin/clang++ -Wp,-v -stdlib=libc++ -x c++ - -fsyntax-only
```

Here's what I get on OS X 10.8.5:

**libstdc++ (GNU)**:

```
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/3.5.0/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory
```

**libc++ (LLVM)**:

```
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/3.5.0/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

So `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1` is a built-in compiler path when using GNU's `libstdc++` (but not LLVM's `libc++`). I'll go even further and tell you its hard coded in LLVM/Clang sources (I build LLVM/Clang from source often):

```
$ cd clang-sources/llvm
$ grep -R "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1" *
tools/clang/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp:      AddGnuCPlusPlusIncludePaths("/usr/include/c++/4.2.1",
tools/clang/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp:      AddGnuCPlusPlusIncludePaths("/usr/include/c++/4.2.1",
tools/clang/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp:      AddGnuCPlusPlusIncludePaths("/usr/include/c++/4.2.1",
tools/clang/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp:      AddGnuCPlusPlusIncludePaths("/usr/include/c++/4.2.1",
tools/clang/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp:      AddGnuCPlusPlusIncludePaths("/usr/include/c++/4.2.1",
```

You can add additional include paths when building LLVM/Clang with `--with-c-include-dirs`.

### ----------

Based on your comment: *"... If I delete ~/anaconda/include/hdf5.h..."*. If you need a new path for the HDF5 package, then use something like:

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I/path/to/preferred/HDF5/hdf5.h"
export CFLAGS="-I/path/to/preferred/HDF5/hdf5.h"
export CXXFLAGS="-I/path/to/preferred/HDF5/hdf5.h"
export LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/preferred/HDF5/lib"
./configure ...
```

You need it in `CPPFLAGS` too because the autotools might run some tests with it.

Then, at runtime:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/preferred/HDF5/lib
./run_the_executable
```

And you can side step `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` ***IF*** you perform static linking against HDF5. But be aware the OS X linker always uses a shared object or dynalib *if* its available. Effectively, it ignores your request for static linking. You will have to `mv` shared object or dynalib off-path while leaving an archive on-path.

### ----------

To muddy the waters a little more... If you are saying "library" when you really want to say "framework", then see this Stack Overflow question about using the `-framework` option: [Clang(LLVM) compile with frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16387484/608639).

Comment: I want to do this for solving this issue. (the one about HDF5 library) https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1717

Comment: sysroot sounds nice!! I'll try. I believe cross-compiling is not problem, because I've worked soooo hard to solved it except for the library search path order. In more detail, I have correct hdf5 header file in /usr/local/include, and also I have wrong hdf5 header file in ~/anaconda/include and it's searched first!!!

Comment: If I delete ~/anaconda/include/*hdf5*.h, it would work fine, but I DON'T want to do that because it contaminates my environment. It's already contaminated though. There's unexpected path on the lib search path...

Comment: Warning for visitors! You cannot specify a file for -I option.

Answer (score 4):

You can go into your project settings and make changes to edit your library search paths very easily.

See how I opened up the settings in this test project screenshot?  There's no paths in my own project there right now; but in your project, there will certainly be duplicate paths (or multiple paths that resolve to the same place).

[image]

Comment: I'll try but it's not a xcode project. I just try to git clone and make.

Comment: I choose "Open another project..." and select the project root dir, but nothing happens.

Comment: drat!  Well at least my answer will help other folks who do have Xcode project problems.

Answer (score 2):

- Open Terminal
- Run `gcc -V`
- Read the information and copy the include path. Mine is
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1

Comment: please follow this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: Do you really mean `-V`? Or should it be `-v`?