# native-image says "unknown type name 'uint8_t'" during compilation

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm getting this error:

```
$ native-image -jar foo.jar bin/java-Objects.bin
...
[bin/java-Objects.bin:24855]    classlist:   1,143.29 ms,  0.96 GB
[bin/java-Objects.bin:24855]        (cap):   1,803.60 ms,  0.96 GB
[bin/java-Objects.bin:24855]        setup:   2,304.75 ms,  0.96 GB
Error: Error compiling query code (in /var/folders/vl/633jwjvn2jvbj9zfg1sgglhw0000gp/T/SVM-3396448792019069231/PosixDirectives.c). Compiler command '/usr/bin/cc -Wall -Werror -ObjC -o /var/folders/vl/633jwjvn2jvbj9zfg1sgglhw0000gp/T/SVM-3396448792019069231/PosixDirectives /var/folders/vl/633jwjvn2jvbj9zfg1sgglhw0000gp/T/SVM-3396448792019069231/PosixDirectives.c' output included error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:202:2:
error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'
```

I'm with Clang:

```
$ clang --version
Homebrew clang version 13.0.0
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
```

It seems that the problem is with this code in `sys/resource.h`:

```
#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#include <stdint.h>
#endif /* __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL */
```

This line with `stdint.h` doesn't get included and that's why `uint8_t` doesn't get defined.

Comment: Do you know if '__DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL' is true?

Comment: Could you share a working simple example that gives this error when you compile?

Comment: @RobbingDaHood obviously, it's not true. That's why the `stdint.h` is not loaded :(

Comment: what if you roughly remove the condition, and import it whatever..?

Comment: @RobbingDaHood this is my code: [`Objects.java`](https://github.com/yegor256/fibonacci/commit/fe849f486b1ac8eef1f3e992d655bcfd131f0a36#diff-a80da4b27a0b8498a0819fc59738e3dce9b2ef4a60431155fc1206d7bfb9bfab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible solution

Please, consider trying to follow the instruction from [quarkus/faq.adoc at main · quarkusio/quarkus](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/b69b6318dd1befaf48b7c14bc32dcbccc54d5b79/docs/src/main/asciidoc/faq.adoc):

> ### 1. Native compilation
>
> Native executable fails on macOS with `error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'`
>
> Your macOS has the wrong `*.h` files compared to the OS and no gcc compilation will work. This can happen when you migrate from versions of the OS. See [Cannot compile any C++ programs; error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029309/cannot-compile-any-c-programs-error-unknown-type-name-uint8-t)
>
> The solution is to
>
> - `sudo mv /usr/local/include /usr/local/include.old`
> - Reinstall XCode for good measure
> - (optional?) `brew install llvm`
> - generally reinstall your brew dependencies with native compilation
>
> The executable should work now.

The purpose of (the idea behind) renaming the `include` directory (from `include` to `include.old`) seems to be explained in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47401866).

## Additional references

- Related question. May contain some possible solutions. [Broken c++ std libraries on macOS High Sierra 10.13 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872922/broken-c-std-libraries-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13).