# Properly adding darwin.apple_sdk to a nix-shell

Tags: nix

I've run into these issues a few times, and have yet to find a solution. My environment has Xcode Command-Line tools installed, but since installing Nix, Clang has been having a difficult time locating macOS SDK frameworks. I know these are present, as if I switch to a new user which has not had Nix installed, I'm able to build these without issue.

As an example,

```
{very long command invocation snipped}
/Users/paulcolusso/Developer/heartbeat/server2/target/debug/deps/libsqlx_macros-95911fe3462937f2.dylib" "-Wl,-dead_strip" "-dynamiclib" "-Wl,-dylib" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: ld: framework not found SystemConfiguration
          clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


error: could not compile `sqlx-macros` due to previous error
```

I've discovered that the macOS SDK derivations do exist, such as the [following from the nix discourse](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/compile-a-rust-binary-on-macos-dbcrossbar/8612) and adding `darwin.apple_sdk.frameworks.SystemConfiguration` derivation does indeed resolve the issue. The question [How can I make macOS frameworks available to clang in a Nix environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161225/how-can-i-make-macos-frameworks-available-to-clang-in-a-nix-environment) also touches on this.

That being said, it is a little time consuming to slowly add each framework, as needed. Is there a way to install the entire `apple_sdk` derivation into my home-manager or a nix-shell I can drop into? If not that, a way to escape out of the Nix sandbox without keeping another user account on hand?

Comment: I don't think having a Nix installation should affect non-Nix programs' ability to find system files in any way. Maybe it's because of something specific to your installation. Perhaps someone in the Nix on macOS room can help: https://matrix.to/#/#macos:nixos.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to install the entire apple_sdk derivation into my home-manager or a nix-shell I can drop into?

No/Yes. You could code something that collects all attrs and adds them or just copy them from https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/os-specific/darwin/apple-sdk/frameworks.nix

> If not that, a way to escape out of the Nix sandbox without keeping another user account on hand?

You can disable it with `sandbox = false` in `nix.conf` ([https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/command-ref/conf-file.html#:~:text=Default%3A%20false-,sandbox,-If%20set%20to](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/command-ref/conf-file.html#:%7E:text=Default%3A%20false-,sandbox,-If%20set%20to)) but keep in mind that this is mostly untested and on linux some things only build in the sandbox.

Comment: "something that collects all attrs": in home-manager, `home.packages = with pkgs; [ ... ] ++ (builtins.attrValues darwin.apple_sdk.frameworks);`

Answer (score 4):

For people who google this, using nix and Rust on an apple M2, adding this to your flake.nix solved it for me:

```
            nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [
              rustToolchain
              darwin.apple_sdk.frameworks.Foundation
              # list of frameworks in case you need another: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/os-specific/darwin/apple-sdk/frameworks.nix
            ];
```

Comment: could you elaborate on where exactly should that be in `flake.nix`? As of now, I haven't been able to make it work

Comment: @sukhmel unfortunately, soon after answering this, I realized that developing on a Mac M2 for Linux slowed me down far more than the possible speed up of the M2 chip, and so I reverted to developing on Linux directly, so I cannot verify this directly, but the following is what I seem to have last: ```
devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
  nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [ gcc rustToolchain darwin.apple_sdk.frameworks.Foundation ];
  RUST_SRC_PATH="${pkgs.latest.rustChannels.stable.rust-src}/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/";
};
```